# I have a function that makes an array and shuffles it but I don't know how to call it in the way I want to

Tags: c#

This is a function that makes an array and fills it from `LoLim` till `HiLim` and then shuffles the order:

```
 static Random random = new Random();        //these two statics are to make a random number, i need the first static to be outside the function so it won't keep making the same random number
    static int RandomNum(int LoLim, int HiLim, int index)
    {
        var nums = Enumerable.Range(LoLim,HiLim).ToArray();  //these next lines make an array from LoLim to HiLim and then shuffle it 

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = random.Next(nums.Length);
            int temp = nums[randomIndex];
            nums[randomIndex] = nums[i];
            nums[i] = temp;

        }
        return nums[index];
```

Then I have this function that makes a 2 dimensional array and then prints it.  It uses `RandomNum` but not in the way I want to, but I don't know how to make it work.

```
static Array Matrix(int Rows, int Columns) //this is a function to initiate and print the array
    {
        int[,] LotteryArray = new int[Rows, Columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < LotteryArray.GetLength(0); i++)  //this is a series of loops to initiate and print the array
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < LotteryArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                LotteryArray[i, j] = RandomNum(1,46,j);       //the numbers are supposed to be between 1 and 45, so i tell it to do it until 46 because the upper limit is exclusive
                Console.Write("{0,3},", LotteryArray[i, j]); //the {0,3} the 3 is three spaces after the first variable
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return LotteryArray;
```

Basically I want it to call to `RandomNum` every "row" so it could shuffle the array, then I want it to pull out `nums[index]` and print it out. The reason I want this is so I can have non repeating random numbers in every row.  For example: I don't want a row to be "21, 4, 21, 5, 40, 30".

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(LoLim,HiLim)` has the syntax `start, count`, not `min, max`

Comment: @xanatos i don't understand. is it supposed to be `RandomNum(1,45,j)`?

Comment: Muffinator Enumerable.Range(10, 45) will return numbers from 10 to 54

Comment: Please note that you missed one `}`in each of your functions. It should cause an error.

Comment: I have to tell the truth... sadly not one of those lines of code can be saved :-(

Comment: @Eminem i'm not i copy pasted this, i just did it badly, the `}`'s are there

Comment: For shuffling you are using the wrong algorithm showed here http://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/, plus in general there are 2^225 possible shuffles of a deck of 52 cards, while Random can't generate so many "different" sequences, because it starts with a seed of 2^32 possible values. see for example http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php (quite long)

Comment: @xanatos the shuffling works fine, this is just a little school project and `Random` works just fine for what i need. the problem is that i don't how to call to the function properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, even if it worked. The "logical" problems are:

- You are using a biased shuffling algorithm. You should use Fisher-Yates to do correct shuffling (see http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/)
- If you really want to do a "good" shuffling, you shouldn't use the `Random` number generator, and instead use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` (see http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php, but note that this is a much lesser problem than the other other one... we can survive with "a little less random" shuffles, if are the generated shuffles are all equiprobable)
- You are using wrongly the arguments of `Enumerable.Range()`

Your coding problem is different: you have to *save* the shuffled row somewhere, and then take the first *column* values.

Here I'm using a class to encapsulate a row with shuffling

```
public class ShuffledRow
{
    public static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    public readonly int[] Row;

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates and shuffles some numbers
    /// from min to max-1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="min"></param>
    /// <param name="max">Max is excluded</param>
    public ShuffledRow(int min, int max)
    {
        int count = max - min;
        Row = Enumerable.Range(min, count).ToArray();
        Shuffle(Row);
    }

    private static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        // Fisher-Yates correct shuffling
        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int j = Random.Next(i + 1);
            T temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Another problem: don't ever use multidimensional arrays in C# unless you know what you are doing. Sadly they are a bastard-and-forgotten child of .NET. Use jagged arrays (arrays of arrays).

```
public static int[][] Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    int[][] lottery = new int[rows][];

    for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
    {
        ShuffledRow sr = new ShuffledRow(1, 46);

        lottery[i] = sr.Row;
        Array.Resize(ref lottery[i], columns);
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Join(",", lottery[i].Select(
                x => string.Format("{0,3}", x))));
    }

    return lottery;
}

public static int[][] Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    int[][] lottery = new int[rows][];

    for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
    {
        ShuffledRow sr = new ShuffledRow(1, 46);

        lottery[i] = new int[columns];

        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            lottery[i][j] = sr.Row[j];
            Console.Write("{0,3},", lottery[i][j]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    return lottery;
}
```

I have prepared two versions of the *Matrix* function, one that is more similar to the one you are using, one that is more LINQ and "advanced".

Comment: this is super useful i'm figuring out how this works and how to make it work with the rest of my code. but i have a followup question: why are multidimensional arrays the bastard and forgotten child of .NET?

Comment: @Muffinator Because they were already badly supported in .NET 1.0/1.1, and then when LINQ was born they were totally dead, because they don't support the `IEnumerable<>` interface.

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you again but how do i create an object with that class?  i tried this `ShuffledRow[] WinRow = new ShuffledRow(1,6);` but it's telling me i can't implicitly convert. and i tried this `ShuffledRow[] WinRow = new ShuffledRow.Shuffle(1,6);` but it's telling me `Shuffle` is used like a type.

Comment: @Muffinator There is an example of use inside the `public static int[][] Matrix(int rows, int columns)`. Each `ShuffledRow` is a single row, not an array of rows. `ShuffledRow sr = new ShuffledRow(1, 46)`

Answer (score 0):

to generate random numbers really do not use random function, use this:

```
private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    // Main method. 
    public static int[] generateTrueRandomOK()
    {
        const int totalRolls = 2500;
        int[] results = new int[50]; //Number of random ints that you need

        // Roll the dice 25000 times and display 
        // the results to the console. 
        for (int x = 0; x < totalRolls; x++)
        {
            byte roll = RollDice((byte)results.Length);
            results[roll - 1]++;
        }

        return results;
    }

    // This method simulates a roll of the dice. The input parameter is the 
    // number of sides of the dice. 

    public static byte RollDice(byte numberSides)
    {
        if (numberSides <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberSides");

        // Create a byte array to hold the random value. 
        byte[] randomNumber = new byte[1];
        do
        {
            // Fill the array with a random value.
            rngCsp.GetBytes(randomNumber);
        }
        while (!IsFairRoll(randomNumber[0], numberSides));
        // Return the random number mod the number 
        // of sides.  The possible values are zero- 
        // based, so we add one. 
        return (byte)((randomNumber[0] % numberSides) + 1);
    }

    private static bool IsFairRoll(byte roll, byte numSides)
    {
        // There are MaxValue / numSides full sets of numbers that can come up 
        // in a single byte.  For instance, if we have a 6 sided die, there are 
        // 42 full sets of 1-6 that come up.  The 43rd set is incomplete. 
        int fullSetsOfValues = Byte.MaxValue / numSides;

        // If the roll is within this range of fair values, then we let it continue. 
        // In the 6 sided die case, a roll between 0 and 251 is allowed.  (We use 
        // < rather than <= since the = portion allows through an extra 0 value). 
        // 252 through 255 would provide an extra 0, 1, 2, 3 so they are not fair 
        // to use. 
        return roll < numSides * fullSetsOfValues;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand well your problem, I thought that the problem is that random go wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could use jagged arrays:

```
Random random = new Random(); 
int[] RandomNum(int LoLim, int HiLim)
{
    var nums = Enumerable.Range(LoLim,HiLim).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.Next(nums.Length);
        int temp = nums[randomIndex];
        nums[randomIndex] = nums[i];
        nums[i] = temp;

    }

    return nums;
}

int[][] Matrix(int Rows, int Columns)
{
    int[][] LotteryArray = new int[Rows][];

    for (int i = 0; i < LotteryArray.Length; i++)
    {
        LotteryArray[i] = RandomNum(1,46);

        for (int j = 0; j < LotteryArray[i].Length; j++)
        {
           Console.Write("{0,3},", LotteryArray[i][j]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    return LotteryArray;
}
```